# How to short button value ? - CSS

Tags: html, css

I want to short button value using CSS. [image]

Final out put need to like this..
[image]

I need help. Thankyou.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrap the button text in a `<span>`, which has properties to control text overflow and linebreaks.

Have a look at this jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/5hEPZ/

```html
<button>
    <span class=buttontext>Very long text Very long text Very long text</span>
</button>
```

And then the css:

```
.buttontext {
width: 95px;
overflow: hidden;
white-space: nowrap;
display: block;
text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `text-overflow: ellipsis;` for truncating the text in the button.

```css
.truncate {
  padding: 10px;
  width: 250px;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

```html
<button class="truncate">very long textvery long text very long text very long text</button>
```